# Not able to show notification in Huawei device

Tags: android

I am developing a messaging app and i have to show the notification on every new message.

In all other device its working fine, only on Huawei device i am not able to show the notification,If user set the notification method as number from Setting->notifcation.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationCompatBuilder;
Notification notification;
 notificationCompatBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, messageDefaultNotificationChannelId);
 notification = notificationCompatBuilder
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_app_notification)
                .setContentTitle(Html.fromHtml(contentTitle))
                .setStyle(messagingStyle)
                .setSound(getDefaultURI())
                .setContentIntent(mainPendingIntent)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                .addAction(addReply(mainPendingIntent, notificationId, messageNotification.getDate()))
                .addAction(addMarkasRead(mainPendingIntent, notificationId))
                .setContentText(messageNotification.getMessageList().get(0).getText())
                .setDefaults(DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setNumber(number)
                .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_CHAT).build();

 notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
```

In manifest also i added few permission related to huawei device

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.CHANGE_BADGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

Can somebody please help me to figure it out how to handle notification in huawei device. 
I googled but couldnt find any solution for this.

Comment: Did you received your notifi on devices other than huaweii device?

Comment: what android version is the huawei device?

Comment: Yes, other than huawei, i am receiving the notification.

Comment: Yes, other than huawei, i am receiving the notification on all devices.
In huawei device also, there is option to set badge icon as number. If we set this option notification is not coming, otherwise its coming

Comment: any update here?